# After Changing my wordpress permalink, my facebook like counts go wrong

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like, permalinks

(I don't have enough reputation to post with link, so all the http:// will be http:/)

I've changed my wordpress permalink from http:/siteurl/?p=number to http:/siteurl/number/slug

I add a code in header to tell facebook the old post address and the new post address, as below

```html
<?php if (is_single() || is_page() ) { 
        $urlidcheck = get_the_id();
            if($urlidcheck <= 85 ){ 
?>
              <meta property="og:url" content="http:/siteurl/?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
             <link rel="canonical" href="http:/siteurl/?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>" >
      <?php } else { ?>
              <meta property="og:url" content="<?php get_bloginfo('url');  ?>" />
      <?php }  
      } 
?>
```

After I use the Sharing Debugger tool to scrape, it works good but ***temporarily***.

After scraping, the Fetched URL, Canonical URL, and og:url are all right, as below.

> Fetched URL   http:/siteurl/47/travel-seoul-running
>
> Canonical URL http:/siteurl/?p=47
>
> meta property=og:url content=http:/siteurl/?p=47

but shows the warnings as below

> [ Circular Redirect Path ]
>    Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).
>
> [ Mismatch og:url and canonical url ]
>   og:url tag in the header is not the same URL as rel='canonical' link in the html.
>
> [Parser Mismatched Metadata]
>   The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:locale:locale'

Few days later, the fb like counts will go to zero suddenly. I use the Sharing Debugger tool to check, it shows that the Canonical URL went wrong, but the og:url still right.

> Fetched URL   http:/siteurl/47/travel-seoul-running
>
> Canonical URL http:/siteurl/47/travel-seoul-running
>
> meta property=og:url content=http:/siteurl/?p=47

also the warnings pop up as below

> [Could Not Follow Redirect Path]
>   Using data from http:/siteurl/?p=47 because there was an error following the redirect path.
>
> [Circular Redirect Path]
>   Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).
>
> [Could Not Follow Redirect]
>   URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.

So I have to scrape manual each post every few days, which is very tiring.

Anyone could give me a hint and instruction about how to solve the problem?
Thank you so much. 
And thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: You would need to keep the old URLs accessible to the FB scraper, so that it does _not_ get redirected to the new one, and they must deliver the relevant OG meta data. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of doing that backwards. Both the canonical and the og:url need to point to the current version of the URL or you are going to get errors. When those don't match the page they're on, they go and fetch the link being referenced in those tags.

So you're essentially telling Facebook to go fetch the old version of the link. Once they go to fetch that version, the server sends a 301 redirect back to the new version of the link. The new one references the old one and it creates an infinite loop or redirecting back and forth for their scraper.

Unfortunately, with most social networks, including Facebook, once you change your permalink settings, you simply lose your share counts because Facebook now views it as an entirely new link.

The only way around this would be to create your own share buttons, and use Facebook's API to request share counts. When requesting those counts via the API, you would have to send two requests, one for each version of the link, and then add them together before displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, Nicholas and CBroe. You let me notice that the problem should be caused by canonical and redirect URLs.

I went back to check the html code in browser, and found that there's another canonical URL in body which only catch the permalink in "http:/siteurl/number/slug" and I don't know which wordpress file it from.

Also, I guess that
When I went on http:/siteurl/?p=47, I was led to http:/siteurl/47/travel-seoul-running. It's just because wordpress guesses the closest address by itself. It's not really a redirect.

So what I do is, I install two plugins "Canonical Seo Wordpress Plugin" and "Redirection". (I know plugins are not a good method. But that's a instant way for me to see how the problems solved.)

The "Canonical Seo Wordpress Plugin" helps me to remove the extant Canonical url which I don't want. And I can set up the Canonical url I want for each post in the post edit page. (But it also took me long time to do for all my posts.)

I also set the 301 redirect for each old post, which used http:/siteurl/?p=number, to http:/siteurl/number/slug with "Redirection" plugin.

I changed the code in header a little bit to

```html
<?php if (is_single() || is_page() ) { 
        $urlidcheck = get_the_id();
            if($urlidcheck <= 85 ){ 
?>
              <meta property="og:url" content="http:/siteurl/?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
      <?php } else { ?>
              <meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>" />
      <?php }  
      } 
?>
```

the place I put the FB like box is

```html
 <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

I use the Sharing Debugger tool to check both of http:/siteurl/47/travel-seoul-running and http:/siteurl/?p=47. They all run good, get the right like counts I have, and show the exactly the same result in both permalink so far.

The two type of permalink looks matched well now, and also the Canonical URLs are correct. I can just use the_permalink() to catch the link to FB, and get the right result.

I still get one warning, which is [Circular Redirect Path]. But the like counts seems run good so far. So I will leave it for one week, keep my eyes on, and see how it works.

I will come back with any further result.
Thank you again.